# Интерфейс пользователя

Tags: java, swing, gui

Здравствуйте. 
Дело вот в чем в лаб 3, задали написать интерфейс на класс лаб 2. 
Почитавши книгу я написала JFrame и заполнила его всем. 
Как теперь мне сделать наследеи класса и как использовать методы. 
вот мой интерфейс 
мне надо использовать переменные 
begin end step 
и методы из лаб 2
. например содание массива по этим начениям и вывод на экран.

код интерфейса и код лаб 2. 
заранее спасибо.

```
package javaapplication5;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

 class JFrames  implements ActionListener  {
     JLabel jlab1;
     JLabel jlab2;
     JButton jbtn;
     JTextField jtf1;
     JTextField jtf2;
     JTextField jtf3;

    JFrames(){
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame ("Variant #5");
        jfrm.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(300,300);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jpnl = new JPanel();
        jpnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (50,50));
        jpnl.setOpaque(true);
        jpnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

        JPanel jpnl2 = new JPanel();
        jpnl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (50,50));
        jpnl2.setOpaque(true);
        jpnl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        jlab1 = new JLabel ("Write begin, end, step");
        jlab2 = new JLabel ("Write begin, end, step");

        jtf1 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf1.setActionCommand("begin");
        jtf1.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtf1);

        jtf2 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf2.setActionCommand("end");
        jtf2.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtf2);

        jtf3 = new JTextField(10);
        jtf3.setActionCommand( "step");
        jtf3.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtf3);

        jbtn = new JButton("Result");
        jbtn.addActionListener(actionPerfom);
        jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 jlab2.setText("Result");

        }});

        jpnl.add(jbtn);
        jpnl.add(jtf1);
        jpnl.add(jtf2);
        jpnl.add(jtf3);
        jpnl.add(jlab1);
        jpnl2.add(jlab2);

        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jpnl);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jpnl2);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);

     }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new NewClass();
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

---

```
package javaapplication5;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Allgol{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Allgol program = new Allgol();
        program.run();

    }   
    private double[] arrayX;
    private double[] arrayY;
    double  EPS= 1e-6;

    public void run() {
        double start = 0.2;
        double end = 2.8;
        double step = 0.002;
    arrayX = createX(start, end, step);
    arrayY = createY(arrayX);
    Print();}

    private void Print(){
        System.out.printf("MinY =: %6.3f\n", arrayY[MinY(arrayY)]);
        System.out.println("Number minY: " + MinY(arrayY));
        System.out.printf("MaxY = %6.3f\n", arrayY[MaxY(arrayY)]);
        System.out.println("Number maxY: " + MaxY(arrayY));
        System.out.printf("Sum = %6.3f\n", sum(arrayY));
        System.out.printf("arith mean у = %6.3f\n", arithMean(arrayY));}

    double[] createX( double start, double end, double step) {
        double[] res = new double[size(start,end,step)];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            res[i] = start + i * step;
        }      
        return res;
    }

     double[] createY(double[] arrayX) {
        double[] res = new double[arrayX.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            res[i] = amount(arrayX[i]);

        }
        return res;
    }

    double amount(double x) {
        final double a=2.3;
        if (x > 2.3 ) {
            return 1.5*a*cos(pow(x,2));
        } 
        else if (x<0.3 ) {
            return 3*a*tan(x);
        }
        else {
            return pow((x-2),2)+6*a;
        }
    }

    int size(double start, double end, double step) {
        return (int) Math.round((end - start) / step) + 1;
    }

     int MinY(double[] arrayY) {
        double miny =  arrayY[0];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayY.length; ++i) {
            if (arrayY[i] < miny) {
                miny = arrayY[i];
                j = i;
            }
        }
        return j;
    }

     int MaxY(double[] arrayY) {
        double maxy = arrayY[0];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayY.length; ++i) {
            if (arrayY[i] > maxy) {
                maxy = arrayY[i];
                j = i;
            }
        }
        return j;
    }

    double sum(double[] array) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

     double arithMean(double[] array) {
        return sum(array) / array.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Выделите создание лейблов begin, end, step в отдельный метод, принимающий на вход имя команды и номер.
2. Выделите в отдельные методы создание панелей: каждый метод возвращает панель, которую вы потом добавляете.
3. Сделайте нужные вам методы в Allgol public и вызывайте их где нужно.